# crimCV different results in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I'm learning how to work with crimCV to cluster my data. My inputs are integers and I replaced NAs with -1 for crimCV considering them as NA. But every time I run this code:

```
model <- crimCV(test, 2)
```

I get different results! Why is that?
Here is the head of my data:

```
  `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`   `7`   `8`   `9`  `10`  `11`  `12`  `13`  `14`  `15`  `16`

1  9    -1    -1    10     3     9     4     1     7     6    -1     4     2     9    -1     3
2 18     0     7     5    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1     3     9     8    -1    -1     6     5
3 27     0    10    -1     5    11    -1     4    11    10     9    -1     8     2     5    13
4 38     5    -1    -1    -1     9     3     5    14     5     2     1    23     5     8     0
5  8     6     7     6     6     4     7     6     0     0    -1     0     6     5     1    -1
6 17     1     2    -1     1     3     4     3     1     1     2     0     1     0     9     0
```

Comment: Have you tried using `set.seed()` in case the code uses randomness?

Comment: @philiptomk I don't understand. My data is fixed. I didn't randomly create it.

Comment: It would be better if you could share your data in a reproducible format, using `dput()`

Comment: @Basti I just run crimCV over and over without making any changes in data. But every time I get a different result.

Answer (score 1):

There is randomness in the function you are calling as @philiptomk clearly suggested in the comments.

Check : https://github.com/cran/crimCV/blob/f102e92b78483ca5fc3c121669948f65f1282300/R/dmZIP.R and https://github.com/cran/crimCV/blob/f102e92b78483ca5fc3c121669948f65f1282300/R/dmZIPt.R which rely on Fortran functions `r_dmzip_init_param`  and `r_dmzipt_init_param` and listed in : https://github.com/cran/crimCV/blob/f102e92b78483ca5fc3c121669948f65f1282300/src/crimCV.f90

Both fortran functions rely on `set_random_seed` which inits the random number generator.

A simple solution to fix the seed generator is to call `set.seed(X)` before running `crimCV()`, with X an integer of your choice.

Comment: If there is randomness in the clustering, can we trust it?

Comment: And also I tried set.seed and I run it before every time I run crimCV but each time it gives me different result